# Start script on login

Tags: ruby, macos, authentication

I have written a ruby daemon and I would like for it to run when I log in. It is normally run by going to the command line and calling `ruby my_ruby_script.rb`. How can I start my daemon on login? (Running 10.6 Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option to add applications etc that need to start at login, you could try writing a shell script or an apple script thing that launches terminal and runs ruby my_ruby_script.rb, or possibly even just add my_ruby_script.rb to this list after adding a `#!/bin/env ruby` line to the top of that file. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2602?viewlocale=en_US gives precise instructions as to how to add an application to be started at login.

If you need to use AppleScript to actually start a terminal application (I believe this is not the case, but I am not in front of my mac now and hence can't test), just create an applescript file with something like

`do shell script "ruby <path>/my_ruby_script.rb"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As Panda said, add:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
```

to the begining of the file, and then you could add a reference to your file inside ~/.bashrc or  ~/.profile or even /etc/profile , depending on your needs.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484429/profile-and-bashrc-doesnt-work-on-my-mac/3484472#3484472

Comment: The problem with adding to ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile is that on OS X neither is executed until the first terminal sessions is started. Also it will execute every time one launches terminal. My understanding was that this was not what was wanted.